# NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK in exe file

Tags: wine, nodejs

I need to run exe file in linux, but when i try to do it i see this :
[image]
How can i fix this? I use Kubuntu 20.04 I know that I can run this program by source code, I need to run it through the exe file

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing what the message suggests and setting the `NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK` variable, but there is no guarantee that this will work:

```
NODE_SKIP_PLATFORM_CHECK=1 wine FunPayServer.exe
```

Comment: Thank you, I just didn't know how to write this command